# Naive and easiest way to decompose independent loop into parallel threads/processes

Tags: python, parallel-processing

1. I have a loop of intensive calculations, I want them to be
   accelerated using the multicore processor as they are independent:
   all performed in parallel. What the easiest way to do that in
   python?
2. Let’s imagine that those calculations have to be summed at the end. How to easily add them to a list or a float variable?

Thanks for all your pedagogic answers and using python libraries ;o)

Comment: Use the `multiprocessing` module.  Send data to processes using `multiprocessing.Queue`.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I have forgotten to mention that before questioning, I searched on the web for solutions (tutorial, python documentation:Threading, multiprocessing, Parallel Python,...). Not more simple solution? An example for me?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From my experience, multi-threading is probably not going to be a viable option for speeding things up (due to the [Global Interpreter Lock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_Interpreter_Lock)).

A good alternative is the [`multiprocessing`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html) module. This may or may not work well, depending on how much data you end up having to pass around from one process to another.

Another good alternative would be to consider using [`numpy`](https://numpy.org/) for your computations (if you aren't already). If you can vectorize your code, you should be able to achieve significant speedups even on a single core. Depending on what exactly you're doing and on your build of `numpy`, it might even be able to transparently distribute the computations across multiple cores.

**edit** Here is a complete example of using the `multiprocessing` module to perform a simple computation. It uses four processes to compute the squares of the numbers from zero to nine.

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

def f(x):
    return x*x

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pool = Pool(processes=4)              # start 4 worker processes
    inputs = range(10)
    result = pool.map(f, inputs)
    print result
```

This is meant as a simple illustration. Given the trivial nature of `f()`, this parallel version will almost certainly be slower than computing the same thing serially.

Comment: Thanks for the nice simple example of using `Pool`, it just worked better for me then the manual. Now my computer can run flat out for several hours ;)

Answer (score 1):

Multicore processing is a bit difficult to do in CPython (thanks to the [GIL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_Interpreter_Lock) ). However, their is the [multiprocessing](http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html) module which allows to use subprocesses (not threads) to split you work on multiple cores.

The module is relatively straight forward to use as long as your code can really be split into multiple parts and doesn't depend on shared objects. The linked documentation should be a good starting point.

Comment: computing is not my job. All tutorial are unclear to me as they directly go into complex examples with network or other complex things for me. I have just a loop that perform independent calculations. (ex: FOR x in list: FACTORIAL(x)). All solutions proposed are quite complex for such a simple concept. I will search further